# Cannot connect through RDP

Tags: active-directory, windows-7-x64, remote-desktop, rdp

I have a veru bizare issue.

When trying to connect via RDP to a remote laptop which has been taken off the network for a few days. When connected again to the network, i cannot RDP into it using DNS name but can using IP. OS is windoes 7 Enterprise x64 using AD.

Taking it off the domain and adding it again does not help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS was the issue. It was not releasing the associated IP. Had to purge all old data and schedule auto periodic purge.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping the DNS name via the command prompt?  Sounds like rejoining the network may have assigned a different IP to the alias.

To rule out firewall issues you could also disable firewalls on both temporarily and try again - though I doubt a firewall is the problem because you're able to access it via the IP address.

Comment: Yes i can ping it by its DNS name and i have already tried all possible routes including disabling firewall.